# Обработка данных в мультипотоке

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Есть у меня функция для обработки данных, но оно выполняется медленно, где то 8 минут, а данных пару десятков тысяч. Как можно сделать для этой функции мультипоточность чтобы ускорить процесс.

Функция выглядит следующим образом:

```
def obrabotka(dan):
    for result in dan['results']:
        ticker = str(result['tickers']).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("',", ",").replace("'", "$")
        dat = str(result['published_utc']).replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "")
        ur = result['article_url']
        date = pickle.load(open('data', 'rb'))
        if dat > date:
            pickle.dump(dat, open('data', 'wb'))
            print(f'{dat}\n{ticker}\n{ur}')
```

Comment: Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1331463/218971 есть пример разбиения списка на сегменты и обработка каждого в своем потоке. Только, во-первых, далеко не факт, что это поможет. Причину тормозов вы же так и не нашли. А во-вторых, у вас тут возникнут проблемы с синхронизацией переменной `date` (и записью ее для хранения в файле), а так же записью результата, которые, вполне вероятно, съедят весь выигрыш (даже если он будет).

Comment: Еще раз повторю то, что писал в оригинальном вопросе. Вам нужно профилировать программу, чтоб понять, где у нее узкие места (т.е. где тратится время) и потом уже оптимизировать. Покажите результат профилирования для этой функции - подскажем, что можно сделать. Многопоточность это один из (и не всегда лучший) вариант.